# Can I get the status whether Topic is enable in my org and whether it is enabled on Account using apex?

Tags: apex

I am working on Topic object in one of my feature using Apex. And I think I should check whether topic is enabled in the org and the object I want to use as well, which is Account object. How can I do this using Apex? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try describe call like below to find if Topic is Enabled

```
public boolean isTopicEnabled(){
   try {
     SObject so = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Topic').newSObject();
     return true;
   }catch(Exception ex) {
     return false;
    }
}
```

Once you previous method as true you can now try inserting TopicAssignmet for Account record

```
public boolean isTopicEnabledForAccount(){

 //Insert a Topic
 Topic testTopic = new Topic();
  testTopic.Name = 'TestXXXXX';
  insert testTopic;

  Account acc = new Account();
  acc.Name = 'TopicTestAccountXXXX';
  insert acc;

  try{
     TopicAssignment accountTopic = new TopicAssignment();
     accountTopic.EntityId = acc.Id;
     accountTopic.TopicId = testTopic.Id;
     insert accountTopic;
     //Delete the records here ..
     return true;
  }catch(exception e){
      return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I want. Many thanks, Mohith.

Comment: @Dongyu Please mark the answer if it helped you .Thanks

Comment: Is this the only option? I didn't like the try-catch approach